# Why are only 3 pins connected on a dual gang pot?

Tags: potentiometer, mixer, stereo

First post on this platform... I am wondering if anyone knows why in some DJ Mixers (e.g. Pioneer) which use dual gang pots for channel faders, only 3 of the 6 available pins are connected. Also, looking at the schematics it looks like one of the 2 resistor elements of the pot is not even connected. Hence my question would be why not use a single gang pot in this case?

Comment: Probably because a single-gang pot that had the other physical characteristics they wanted was not available. Or perhaps they use the dual-gang pot elsewhere and they wanted to keep their inventory control simple.

Comment: pots can be used many ways,, as pots, as variable resistors as mixers.... you would need to show pictures..

Comment: And also costs.... cheaper to buy bulk of one type than many different types.

Comment: It's a good question that should not have been put on HOLD so quick. but certainly needs expertise, not simply "opinion"

Comment: Nah, its got my opinion vote.

Comment: Maybe they wanted to reduce the number of BOM line items? IDK, audio folks are weird

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I thought it would be something like inventory, or simplified BOM as I do not see any technical rationale for not using one of the resistive elements. I also noticed in some designs also using dual-gang pots, the input pins of the 2 elements is shorted (combined) on the PCB. Same for the output pin (and ground). Combining ground pins is self explanatory, but what about the input and output pins? What would be the purpose? (and wouldn't doing this place the 2 resistive elements in parallel, therefore dividing the resistance value by 2?)